# A connected graph retracts onto any connected subgraph (Hatcher 1.A.2)

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's book "Algebraic Topology", problem 2 in section 1.A asks to prove that a connected graph retracts onto any connected subgraph. I don't see how I could use covering spaces in this setting. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why would you use covering spaces? Just construct the retract one edge at a time.

Comment: I was thinking about using covering spaces because it's the goal of this section. I also thought about cnstructing a retract edge by edge, but I don't know how to do it in a systematic way.

Comment: That section 1.A has its own goal, namely to explain graphs.